# Url based on dark/light mode error "Cannot use instance member..."

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to use a style URL to my SwiftUI / UIViewRepresentable view using Mapbox that switches the style URL based on the device being in light or dark mode but I get the following error:

**"Cannot use instance member 'style' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available"**

I am not sure why I am getting this error and tried making an initializer based off answers from other similar questions on SO?

How can I make this logic work in my code?

THANK YOU

**I tried using this initializer but get the same error?**

```
var mapboxStyleURL: String
    
init() {
    self.mapboxStyleURL = "mapbox://styles/customStyle/" + 
    (colorScheme == .dark ? "cl03fsdfsdfsfsdfsos" : "cksdfsdfsfsdfsdfdsfd0h")
 }
```

```
struct MapboxMapViewRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    @EnvironmentObject var session: SessionStore
    @EnvironmentObject var mapVM : MapViewModel
    
    var styleURL: String {
        "mapbox://styles/customStyle/" + (colorScheme == .dark ? "cl03fsdfsdfsfsdfsos" : "cksdfsdfsfsdfsdfdsfd0h")
    }
    
    let mapView: MGLMapView = MGLMapView(frame: .zero, styleURL: URL(string: styleURL))
    // ^ 
    // Cannot use instance member 'style' within property initializer; property 
    // initializers run before 'self' is available
        
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MGLMapView { }
   
    func updateUIView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, context: Context) { }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator { }
    
}
```

Comment: just use `lazy var mapView`. Forget about the init.

Comment: That also didn't work for me (lazy var mapView) because then I had to make the makeUIView & updateUIVIew mutating and then the view didn't conform to UIViewRepresentable??

Comment: please edit your question with your current approach and a [mcve]